# How To Iterate Through a Collection of Images with Navigation Buttons Using Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am learning how to program and am working on my final project for my intro class.

I am building a website using the Flask framework. The purpose of the website is to allow the user to upload images and display them to the public. I store those images in a folder. I use Bootstrap and put the images each on a card. Since there may be many images, I want to be able to show a few at a time and allow the user to click forward and backward through the set.

I am able to loop through the whole list successfully. I have also found a way to show only 6 at a time.

I have a global variable STEP which is basically a counter that starts at 0.
I have a global variable INTERVAL which defines how many images to load each time (6).
"rows" is the SQL query that I pass to the page with info about each image.

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            {% for row in rows[step:(step+interval)] %}
            <div class="col-md-4 p-3">
                <div class="card-deck h-100">
                    <div class="card text-center" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img src="../static/uploads_Andrea/{{ row.filename }}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">{{ row.title }}</h4>
                        <h6 class="card-title"><i>{{ row.date }}</i></h6>
                        <p class="card-text" text-align:center;>{{ row.description }}</p>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            {% endfor %}

        </div>
```

I want to display after each set of six images two buttons: "older" and "newer" (the images have dates associated and are displayed in reverse chronological order).

I am asking for some help in understanding how to proceed from here. I wanted to just have Flask recognize which button is clicked and then either add or subtract INTERVAL from the current STEP and run the loop again. However, I can't find anything suggesting this capability in Flask.

I suspect that I need to create a form that sends the button click back to the app so that the app can add or subtract INTERVAL from the current STEP and refresh the page and run the loop. But I cannot find anything that suggests how a button can initiate this action.

Any help or direction would be appreciated. I have seen some answers get close but appear to be much more complex than what I am looking for.

I tried to have a button action that would pass back to the app the need to add/subtract interval from step and re-POST the page but really did not know how to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

Please

1. Update your Flask code to accept optional GET parameters for `starting_record` and `page_size`, which would then also be used in your SQL query
2. Use the template tool (e.g., Jinja) to create links for before and after pages using something like `<a href="loadimages?starting_record=$(starting_record - page_size)&page_size=$(page_size)">previous page</a>`

Hope this helps.